# How can I add new a new object with key and values pairs to the existing state in class based component?

Tags: reactjs

I've got a state where I need to pass a new object.

So the problem is in my setState, I don't know how to pass a new object into my existing state?

This is my state:

```
 state = {
        data1: [],
        loading: null,
        input: { test: 1, test: 2, test: 3, test: 4, test: 5)
 }
```

This is my function which is adding my object into the state.

```
 getInputs = (data) => {
        this.setState({ input: { ...this.state.input, data} });
    }
```

So the output is:

```
 state = {
        data1: "11",
        data: {data2: "22", data3: "33"}
        loading: null,
        input: { test: 1, test: 2, test: 3, test: 4, test: 5)
 }
```

What I need is:

```
 state = {
        data1: [],
        loading: null,
        input: { test: 1, test: 2, test: 3, test: 4, test: 5),
        //my content here with key and value pairs
        data2: "22", 
        data3: "33"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need to spread the object into state, rather than into the `input` property of it:

```
getInputs = (data) => {
  this.setState({ ...this.state, ...data });
}
```